# How to make text created with CSS :after Element selectable?

Tags: css

i'm creating text with css :after. But I'm not able to select the resulting text (e.g. for copy&paste).
is it possible to make it selectable?

```
<div>foo</div>

div:after{
    content: '   123';

}
```

[sample](http://jsfiddle.net/jfbc4/2/)

Comment: So you expect the result to be: `<div>foo   123</div>`? :)

Comment: exactly. And both, the letters and the numbers shall be selectable.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this has been a long-running issue that is still not resolved. This bug thread, which is still current, goes back to 1999!

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=12460