# Subdivide or reorder HTML content by css means

Tags: html, css

For a static web page and with javascript forbidden (because of firewall settings) I would like to have the possibility to display content depending on different css. This css will be different for different user groups (in fact the sites are on different web servers and the HTML is identical, the css not). The following example is not very meaningful because for translation it is not just enough to change the representation of dates but it is meant to describe what I would like to archieve.

```
<span class="xdate">YYYYMMDD</span>
```

should be displayed for one user group (user group 1 with cssfile1) as

```
DD.MM.YYYY
```

and for the other group as

```
MM/DD/YYYY
```

Is that possible by pure CSS / HTML? I. e. it is possible to cut out parts of a string?

Comment: No, that is not really possible using CSS - and if you ask if it is possible via HTML, then the answer is yes, of course, you just need to _change_ the HTML.

Comment: Yes it was just an idea to overcome the situation/limitation with these websites. Translation and different files are the solution.Thx, Peter

Comment: There is some possibility to insert text: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741312/using-css-to-insert-text), but one can't split strings.