# Button put text right corner with class

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a span like that

```
<span class="btn btn-sm btn-twitter" id="Teacher" >TheTeacher</span>
```

I want to add x char character with class so, when i write this code

```
$("#Teacher").addClass("ClassOfX");
```

I want to get this result inner the button

[image: Image 1]

When i write this code

```
$("#Teacher").removeClass("ClassOfX");
```

I want to get this result

[image: Image 2]

I want to code like that. Can i create it ??? I dont want to add element inner the span tag.. because i have alot of code to get inner span text..

```
InsertState($("#Teacher").text());
```

I can't rebuild this code block because i can mistake one of the code. I have alot of code like InsertState function.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741312/using-css-to-insert-text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have:

```
classofx::before {
  position: relative;
  content: 'x';
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir i will try it.

Comment: It will put the X on the top corner, but if you want the X to do something you ought to use an actual html element.

Comment: Okay sir ,i know the usage content tag after this moment